# How to limit the performance overhead caused by Tensor.to() in Torch?

Tags: python, performance, neural-network, pytorch

I'm working on a real-time object tracking network based on [Tracktor](https://github.com/phil-bergmann/tracking_wo_bnw) and the [mmdetection](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection) framework. I'm simulating a constant stream of input data by running it with a batch size of 1. I noticed a very large slowdown caused by the constant usage of the .to() Torch method, over which I have no control, to my knowledge.

What techniques can be used to limit the overhead caused by the transfer of data from the CPU to the GPU?

Here's Pycharm's profiling with the important links highlighted:

[image]

And the code corresponding to the last box before .to():

```
def grid_anchors(self, featmap_sizes, device='cuda'):
    """Generate grid anchors in multiple feature levels.

    Args:
        featmap_sizes (list[tuple]): List of feature map sizes in
            multiple feature levels.
        device (str): Device where the anchors will be put on.

    Return:
        list[torch.Tensor]: Anchors in multiple feature levels. \
            The sizes of each tensor should be [N, 4], where \
            N = width * height * num_base_anchors, width and height \
            are the sizes of the corresponding feature lavel, \
            num_base_anchors is the number of anchors for that level.
    """
    assert self.num_levels == len(featmap_sizes)
    multi_level_anchors = []
    for i in range(self.num_levels):
        anchors = self.single_level_grid_anchors(
            self.base_anchors[i].to(device),
            featmap_sizes[i],
            self.strides[i],
            device=device)
        multi_level_anchors.append(anchors)
    return multi_level_anchors
```

And the main loop that loads the images and runs the tracking:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from tqdm import tqdm

data_loader = DataLoader(seq, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
for i, frame in enumerate(tqdm(data_loader)):
    if len(seq) * tracktor['frame_split'][0] <= i <= len(seq) * tracktor['frame_split'][1]:
        with torch.no_grad():
            tracker.step(frame)
        num_frames += 1
```